# How do i avoid calling the same sql statement over and over

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `sql` statement that says

```
SELECT coalesce((Select sum(SomeNumber) 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT IDs...)), 0) MyFirstNumber,
coalesce((Select sum(SomeNumber2) 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT IDs...)), 0) MySecondNumber
```

How can I make the `(SELECT IDs...)` query statement be called only once, say before the statement above.

I think it would be something like

```
DECLARE @MyIDs
SET @MyIDs = SELECT IDs FROM TABLE WHERE ...

SELECT coalesce((Select sum(SomeNumber) 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID NOT IN (@MyIDs)), 0) MyFirstNumber,
coalesce((Select sum(SomeNumber2) 
FROM Table 
WHERE ID NOT IN (@MyIDs)), 0) MySecondNumber
```

Comment: Does the Select IDs return a single row or multiple rows?

Comment: In your example, both `SUM` functions are done against `table`... I'm assuming that this is a contrived example, and that your actually query is performing `SUM` on two *different* tables?

Comment: You can use a common table expression (CTE) to define the inner query first: `WITH ctename AS () SELECT * FROM ctename` etc. so that YOU don't have to repeat it.  But as to what the execution plan will actually do, you will need to look at it.  If you want something actually materialized to a table first, the only way to ensure that it is done that way is to do it yourself.  You have left out exactly what is in those inner queries, so it's hard to know if they need to be correlated or not (you have no FROM in your outer query either)

Comment: The (SELECT IDs...) returns many results of IDs. Originally I made a separate database call and simply built a string from the first results and then included that string in the where statement like this: SELECT coalesce((Select sum(SomeNumber) FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (12,14,6534,234,65465,23,45 ......))

But then i ended up having soo many IDs that it through a sql error, so i had to just include the query (SELECT IDs FROM TABLE ...) but now i am having a performance issue and would like to get the ids in some set variable and then reference the variable. :\

Comment: And TABLE is one of my tables, not the sql keyword, should have wrote SomeTable, sorry

Comment: It sounds like you should be using `JOIN`s, potentially.  Provide us with starting (sample) data tables, and desired results, and we may be able to help you better.  The direction you seem to be heading is extremely counter to the way SQL is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about joining with that subselect and fitering only where the join is false ( returns null)

```
SELECT sum(coalesce(SomeNumber,0)) MyFirstNumber
       ,sum(coalesce(SomeNumber2,0)) MySecondNumber
FROM   Table 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT IDs.. FROM Table ) AS Filter ON Table.ID = Filter.ID
WHERE  Filter.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: How would this work if i had an additional SELECT coalesce that was not restricted by the IDs??
i.e.
SELECT coalesce((Select sum(SomeNumber) FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT IDs...)), 0) MyFirstNumber,
 coalesce((Select sum(SomeNumber2) FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT IDs...)), 0) MySecondNumber,
coalesce((Select sum(SomeNumber3) FROM Table WHERE a = 1), 0)

Otherwise I think this will work if I break it into two query calls

Comment: if the additional select as a different criteria.. then you can't do it with joins..(at least so simply) because they will return different amount of rows.. and the sums will probably not be right also..

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the amount in one SELECT statement

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SomeNumber), 0) AS MyFirstNumber, 
       COALESCE(SUM(SomeNumber2), 0) AS MySecondNumber
FROM Table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT IDs FROM TABLE WHERE...)
```

If need different conditions you can use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression within SUM() functions

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SomeNumber), 0) AS MyFirstNumber, 
       COALESCE(SUM(SomeNumber2), 0) AS MySecondNumber,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN SomeNumber3 END), 0) AS MyThirdNumber
FROM Table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT IDs FROM TABLE WHERE...)
```